# python draggable tasks by ressource gantt

Tags: python, drag-and-drop, task

I have to build an application where I have tasks assigned to resources.
I would need to design a kind of Gantt chart where I have a row for each resources (approximately 200) and on each row there are several tasks assigned to the corresponding resource (up to 30 in a month).

I have to move the tasks among the resources in order to reallocate the corresponding task from one resource to an other by using drag and drop.

Also there is an another list of tasks which have not been allocated to a resource, I have to allocate them by drag and drop to a chosen resource.

There is no relationship between the tasks, just simple "boxes" put to the right position (right row and datetime column).

Altogether I have to display around 4000 tasks in a month and being able to move them along, so the performance must be fine.

All the solutions I've seen (matplotlib, python-gantt, etc.) are (as I've understood) just static display of tasks, no dynamic drag and drop interaction.

Are there any ready to use (possible open source) gantt chart type of solution for python I could use for my project?

Comment: if it is completely necessary to use python... have you tried with PyQt ? or maybe QT Designer? i think winPython has a good environment to develop a GUI

Comment: The issue is not the GUI design itself but to draw as many objects (task) and move them around in a Gantt chart type of view (and of course store the state in the database, like this task is allocated to that resource). With QT designer I cannot design a monthly grid and put the tasks in it (especially that a task can overlap a day) and move them around. So if for example pyhon-gantt's tasks would be draggable (not just static) and the display performance for 4000 tasks is acceptable, than I would use it.

Comment: So no python GUI programmers over there ? :-(

Comment: I've searched high and low. It was really surprising to me, but I don't think a stock solution exists -- you might have to build one. It seems like there are some ways to [interact with matplotlib using the mouse](https://matplotlib.org/2.2.2/gallery/event_handling/poly_editor.html?highlight=polygoninteractor) .